# How to do something like this in linux shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a shell script that is doing something.I want to print the `Unknown` string where there is blank space in the output.

I want to do check if `(f[1] == "") or (f[2] == "") or (f[3] == ""),` it should be replaced by a `unknown` string and should be written in a single file

```
 if(f[1] == "") printf(fmt, id, f[1], f[2], f[3]) > file
```

where `f[1],f[2],f[3]` if empty should be replaced by `unknown` string

where `f[1]` is the first index, `fmt` is the format specifier I have defined in the code.How to replace these empty spaces with a string in Linux.

Any lead is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: _I have a shell script that is doing something_. As opposed to one that does nothing?

Comment: This question seems to be just about awk, not linux, bash, or shell. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the conditional operator:

```
ec2-describe-instances | awk -F'\t' -v of="$out" -v mof="$file" '
function pr() { # Print accumulated data
    if(id != "")    {   # Skip if we do not have any unprinted data.
        printf(fmt, id, f[1], f[2], f[3]) > of
        if (f[1] == "" || f[2] == "" || f[3] == "") {
            printf(fmt, id, f[1]==""?"Unknown":f[1], f[2]==""?"Unknown":f[2], f[3]==""?"Unknown":f[3]) > mof
        }
    }
    # Clear accumulated data.
    id = f[1] = f[2] = f[3] = ""
}

BEGIN { # Set the printf() format string for the header and the data lines.
    fmt = "%-20s %-40s %-33s %s\n"
    # Print the header
    headerText="Instance Details"
    headerMaxLen=100
    padding=(length(headerText) - headerMaxLen) / 2
    printf("%" padding "s" "%s" "%" padding "s"  "\n\n\n", "", headerText, "") > of
    printf(fmt, "Instance id", "Name", "Owner", "Cost.centre") > of
    printf("%" padding "s" "%s" "%" padding "s"  "\n\n\n", "", headerText, "") > mof
    printf(fmt, "Instance id", "Name", "Owner", "Cost.centre") > mof
}
$1 == "TAG" {
    # Save the Instance ID.
    id = $3
    if($4 ~ /[Nn]ame/) fs = 1           # Name found
    else if($4 ~ /[Oo]wner/) fs = 2         # Owner found
    else if($4 ~ /[Cc]ost.[Cc]ent[er][er]/) fs = 3  # Cost center found
    else next                   # Ignore other TAGs
    f[fs] = $5  # Save data for this field.
}
$1 == "RESERVATION" {
    # First line of new entry found; print results from previous entry.
    pr()
}
END {   # EOF found, print results from last entry.
    pr()
}'
```

Comment: thankyou but I have changed my requirement. I am very sorry to say. can you help me achieving this

Comment: it fullfills my requirement. I have an extra requirement relatetd to this. DO I need to post a new question for that ?

Comment: If it's closely related, you can keep it in this question.

Comment: thanks I want that if the any of the three fields is blank then it should be replaced by `unknown` and at the same time only those records that have any of the three field `unknown` should be written to a file, no other records that have all the three fields present should be written to the file. Also the file should have the heading `Details`at centre.

Comment: Just use an `if` statement, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Can't you just print the heading in the `BEGIN` block? Do you really need that added to the answer?

Comment: Isn't it trivial? `BEGIN {print "Details"}`

Comment: actually the script is not working.I have been given the suggestion that if When you're figuring out that you need to replace empty output fields with "Unknown", it is trivial to add some logic that says if there aren't any empty fields, do not write this line to the file. Doing this is faster and much simpler than post-processing the output to get rid of lines that do not contain "Unknown"!

Comment: What's wrong with the `if` statement in my answer? Anyway, if your script isn't working, you need to post it if you expect anyone to help you fix it.

Comment: Your script works fine for me. You just need to wrap the `if` statement in my answer around the `printf ... > "mof"` so that it only prints lines with `unknown` in them.

Comment: can you modify my script and where should i put the `heading` details in the second file?

Comment: and how can i add the heading in the mof file ? and why u have declared the mof with the awk ?

Comment: I put the heading in the BEGIN block. I assumed that the `mof` was supposed to be a variable with the `MissingXXX` filename, since you didn't use that in your script; I didn't think you wanted to create a file named `mof`. If I'm wrong, you can easily change that back to use the hard-coded filename `"mof"`.

Comment: can you remove the script and add only the previous lines for conditional operator. Thanks